# When creating ApplicationID thru Kickstart how do I access the created applicationId?

Tags: java, fusionauth

If I assign my own applicationId for the defaultTenant then I get error telling Invalid registration role. But if I use default FUSIONAUTH_APPLICATION_ID then I don't have access to this applicationId as it is saved as a blob in the Database. So if you can provide me either a way:

1. To create an admin when using my applicationId for defaultTenantId
2. To access the default application id after it is created thru kickstart

That will be very helpful.

Comment: This is the error I get: {
  "fieldErrors" : {
    "registration.roles" : [ {
      "code" : "[invalid]registration.roles",
      "message" : "The role [admin] does not exist in the Application indicated by the [registration.applicationId] property."
    } ]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The default FusionAuth Application Id cannot be changed. The default can be referenced using `FUSIONAUTH_APPLICATION_ID` . So if you create a new application, you will not be able to use the FusionAuth role named `admin` unless you create that same role in your application.

If you want to create a new application, you can use a hard coded applicationId so it can be used elsewhere, or you can generate one using the `UUID()` function and then store it in a variable.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/installation-guide/kickstart

Comment: Thanks! Once I created my own application Id, I had to create the roles also myself. And then I was able to create users with admin and other roles.